# Struggling with adding depencies to maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am trying to add dependencies to a project using maven, and when I search for mysql dependencies nothing comes up. I have downloaded maven, rebuilt, and updated maven. Nothing has helped this process.

Whenever I load Eclipse I get an error stating:
'Repository registry initialization' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization". For input string: "7 2" under radix 36.

I am on Mac and I'm using MySql 8. Everything else is updated.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are searching for dependencies, and you don't say *which* mysql related dependency you want, but the first result of a google search for `mysql jdbc maven` is https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: Show us your pom.xml.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.